# Speakers go dead on windows 8.1 - when using google hangouts

Tags: windows-8, audio

A problem I get only since getting windows 8.1 - The speakers stop working a few hours into a session.  The work again after a reboot.

The headphones work when the speakers stop working.

In the sound settings box, playback tab, the Digital Audio (S/PDIF) level goes up and down but nothing in the speakers volume level.   Many applications like itunes wont start to playback tracks, realising there is a problem.  Rather than just playing with no sound being heard.  Plays fine with headphones inserted.

No idea what is going on but I dont want to wait for 8.2 or reboot every few hours

Update>

If I make a call on google hangouts, from within gmail , and the call fails - then there is a high chance the sound will stop, but work for headphones.  I dont see the sound fail in any other occurrence.

Comment: Are you sure the speakers aren't what's faulty?  IE: Have you tried a different pair (in the same jack)?  Have you tried those speakers on another computer?

Comment: speakers work fine after a reboot.  Also programs wont play the sound - how would they know there was a problem if it was just in the speaker

Comment: You need to do a MSCONFIG, remove all start up tasks (which are safe to remove) and see if the issue persists. Or, try in safe mode.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying when the speakers stop working, the headphones remain working fine?

Comment: yes headphones remain working fine

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem back in the 90's with my line-in jack... turned out the jack was overheating due to bad airflow.
rebooting gave it (and the video-card above it) a minute or so to cool down.

Comment: no issue with cooling.  Reboot does not take a minute or so like it did in the 90s.  20 seconds later the speakers are working

Answer (score 1):

> the Digital Audio (S/PDIF) level goes up and down

Typically, programs will only output to one sound device - the default - at one time. If you're seeing sound output on a different device from the speakers (e.g. S/PDIF), then it's possible the default output device was changed.

Try setting the default output device back to the speakers. You could also test a specific device by right clicking on it and clicking `Test` in the sound control panel. If this does (temporarily) solve it, the next step would be to determine what could be changing this setting.

---

As for headphones working, if they were USB headphones then they'd turn up as a separate output device, which normally gets automatically set as default - which is consistent with my above theory. Standard line-out headphones are normally using the same sound output device as the speakers (the one belonging to the sound card chipset), and are managed by the audio drivers associated with the card or chipset. They are most often Realtek-branded, though it does depend on the motherboard. Consider looking for a driver update.

Comment: No the output levels move on the the Digital Audio (S/PDIF) although the speakers are the defaulted option.  Test does not output any sound, and the headphones are jack. No driver updates found.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. I've found that disabling and re-enabling the audio device from the control panel fixes it until it goes off again. I don't know a permanent fix.

Comment: thanks Ill try it.  Sometimes if I put in the headphones and remove it works again, but not always.  Ill try it thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the same problem you have in windows 8.1 but while using multiple flash videos at once or after some time. My realteck driver have a function in the settings, something like "Disable input in the back while headphones are plugged in". I changed this setting to "Allow simultaneous playback of two audio streams for input in the front and back". The program restarted the drivers and they work again.

The settings are translated from german and may not be accurate

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> DeviceManager -> Sound, Video and Game Controllers. Right click *Properties* in your default sound card. Open *Driver* tab. If it's enabled, disable. Enable again.

Works without restarting your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced audio issues after windows 8.1 installation, new Microsoft sound drivers seems rather very bad and i'd suggest you to install the official drivers, I myself faced some jack output not working and I forced the win7 drivers installation, then everything was working good ;)

also if you have other speakers you might try using those and see if the issue persists, if not the problem might comme from your speakers...

Comment: drivers say they are ok. Guess have to wait for new drivers to come out.  My problem is intermittent and not every day

Comment: yeah well, 8.1 was also telling me drivers were okay but fact was that it wasn't, try any drivers that are win7 or vista compatible as it's still 6.X kernel there should be no real deal trying those...

Comment: How does this answer the authors question exactly!